# Email id address issue in c# code

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I wrote a simple program in C# Winforms for sending an email  and my code is mentioned below:-

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public MailMessage rtnMail()
        {
            string to = txt_To.Text;
            string from = txt_From.Text;
            string subject = txt_Subject.Text;
            string body = txt_Body.Text;
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
            return message;
        }

         //Button click event

        private void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myanotherid@gmail.com", "password");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Timeout = 500000;
            smtp.Send(this.rtnMail());
        } 

    }
```

when i run this code and put all the values in textboxes like (to, from, body, subject) and click the "Send" button i do end up getting an email at an address

mentioned in the Textbox named txt_To ( which is my recipient gmail account id).But whenever i look at which address(email id) i got this email from in Microsoft

Outlook (which i have configued for my gmail recipeint account), it always says that i got this email from the email address mentioned as first argument in the line of

code below,

```
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myanotherid@gmail.com", "password");
```

My question is, am i doing anything wrong because i expect that email address from which im receiving an email( in my outlook gmail) should be the one that i put in

TextBox named txt_From rather than from "myanotherid@gmail.com" address.

Is there a work around or does there exist an alternate to it.

Comment: what is your from and to address?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's gmail's protection to prevent sender spoofing.

You can't login to GMail as *yogibear@gmail.com* and send an e-mail as *barack.obama@whitehouse.gov*. GMail's SMTP will rewrite the message's header to properly indicate who has really sent the e-mail.

Comment: Jan, actually im not logging in to send an email to any address, its my c# winform which im using as a user interface to send email to my gmail outlook account but i expect that from address should be the one typed in txt_From textbox rather than "myanotherid@gmail.com".

Comment: When you call smtp.Send, it connects to smtp.gmail.com, logs-in with the credentials that you provide and asks it to send the email.

Comment: i got you, but still i think is it possible to work with yahoo smtp or some other smtp to get the job done?

Comment: It may be. It depends on the configuration of the SMTP - one may have more liberal policy, other may have more strict... I think it's pretty reasonable to restrict (or rewrite) the "from:" field to the logged user. It can prevent users from abusing the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should use new mailaddress();

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("someone@something.com", "John Doe");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("someoneelse@something.com", "Jane Doe");
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
```

further reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Gmail does not allow you to specify a different 'from address' unless it is one you have proven belongs to you.

Go to Settings > Accounts > 'Send email as' and add an address there. You can only choose to send from any of the accounts you have configured here.

Comment: i tried "Send email as and add an address", but when i get an email in my outlook, it shows From  [myanotheridgmail.com]; on behalf of; [myid@yahoo.com]. But what if i want to receive an email from any domain in the world in to my gmail account ( the recipient account ), and its almost impossible for me to configure and prove to the gmail that every email ( from any domain in the world) I'm getting in my gmail account is already configured and proved to be mine.There are infinite number of domains all over the world and i have no idea which domain will i be getting an email from.